# I want to call var from another handler function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, logic, alexa-skills-kit

I am doing a project where i need to call a variable from another function and i dont know how to call it here is the code I want to call team1,team2,server from HelloWorldIntentHandler how do i call?

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {

    var team1 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.score.value;
    var team2 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoreone.value;
    var server = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoretwo.value;
    var value1 = Number(team1);
    var value2 = Number(team2);
    var totalteam1 = Math.round(value1 + value1 );
    var totalteam2 = Math.round(value2 + value2 );
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak("score is " + totalteam1)
        .reprompt()
        .getResponse();
}
```

};

```
const PickleballScoreNowHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'PickleballScoreNow';
},
handle(handlerInput) {

    var team1 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.score.value;
    var team2 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoreone.value;
    var server = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoretwo.value;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak("score is " + team1 + team2 + server)
        .reprompt()
        .getResponse();
}
```

};

Comment: Can you please Make the question a bit clear in more explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    var score={};

   canHandle(handlerInput) {
          return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
         && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
        },

 handle(handlerInput) {

**score.team1 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.score.value;
score.team2 =  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoreone.value;
score.server = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.scoretwo.value;**
var value1 = Number(team1);
var value2 = Number(team2);
var totalteam1 = Math.round(value1 + value1 );
var totalteam2 = Math.round(value2 + value2 );
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak("score is " + totalteam1)
    .reprompt()
    .getResponse();
 }
```

-- you may access your all variable like this way.

```
  HelloWorldIntentHandler.score.team1
```

Comment: i am getting error unexepected var in var score = {}